# Determine whether or not a sequence is decreasing in java

Tags: java

I got this question on exam review "Write psuedocode for a program that reads a sequence of integer values and decides whether or not it is a decreasing sequence.  The program will first read in the number of values to process, followed by the values themselves.  The output will be “Yes” if the sequence is decreasing, and “No” otherwise."

Here is my code, but it sometimes does not stop,(for example, when you input 3 2 1). Can someone help me to figure out where I was wrong? Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecreasingOrNot {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int number1, number2;
        boolean decrease = true;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sequence of numbers: ");
        number2 = input.nextInt();
        while (decrease && input.hasNext()){
            number1 = number2;
            number2 = input.nextInt();
            if (number1 < number2){
                decrease = false;
            }
        }
        if (decrease){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the sample input to produce the issue

Comment: might be a mistake with the way you're reading the numbers in, try reading them all in at once and put them in an array then compare

Comment: You are using the first input, which should be the amount of numbers in the sequence, as a number in the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you have no way of breaking out of the loop if the user keeps adding decreasing numbers (which is why it won't break out of the loop if the user enters something like 3 2 1).

Comment: Thank you. I thought input.hasNext() could terminate the loop if I did not input more numbers, but it seems not work as I thought. Is there any way that the loop can be terminated if I press "enter"?